# Windows Azure Extra Small Instance Harddisk Size

Tags: deployment, azure, azure-web-roles

We have a Windows Azure Web Role on two extra-small instances that has been running for weeks without problems. This morning, we unintentionally passed some spending limit, which resulted in Windows Azure shutting down our complete service, without any prior warning!

We removed the spending cap and began to re-deploy the Web Role, with the same codebase that has been running for weeks. To our astonishment, we got the deployment error

`Validation Errors: Total requested resources are too large for the specified VM size.`

We upgraded the deployment to two small instances instead of the extra-small instances, whereupon deployment was working again. Now, the web role is back in the web.

However, we still don't understand **why our deployment was suddenly too big for an extra-small instance**. We didn't change one bit since the last successful deployment to extra-small instances. We then tried to remove the deployment size by moving some files to Azure Storage, but even after reducing the package file by more than 1 MB, deployment still failed.

The `cspkg` file, the deployment package, is currently at `9'359 KB`. If unzipped, the complete `sitesroot` folder's size is `14 MB`. Which is way below the `19'480 KB` limit for the x-small instance.

Before we lose more time with trial-and-error, here's my question: **How exactly are those `19'480 KB` calculated? Is it just the `sitesroot` folder, or the zipped package, or is it the `sitesroot` and `approot` folder together, or the whole unzipped package?**

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Could you verify if your local resources exceed 20 GB:

[image]

Comment: Now I understand, our Local Storage was set to `20'000 MB`, so it exceeded the maximum for X-Small instances. Still wondering why deployment has been working for several months.

Comment: How many local resources did you have? And did you also activate diagnostics?

Comment: I have only one local resource `DiagnosticStore`, which was set to 20'000. When I reduced it to 18'000, deployment was working again.

Comment: I was faced with the same issue after upgrading to OS version 3, the same setting worked fine on OS version 2.